# EntityFramework creating 130+ connections

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlconnection

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896325%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), entity framework is supposed to close its connections after a specific operation (e.g. SaveChanges()).

Amazon is barking at me about too many connections in my SQL Server instance (140 connections). 100 of these connections in sp_who2 display a ProgramName of "EntityFramework".

Is it OK for EF to create all these connections? Is there an application level clean up that is missing? Would initiating periodic garbage collection help clean these up?

Comment: No, what the article states is : When a query method is called, the connection is opened, and it remains open until the ObjectResult has been completely consumed or disposed.  If are seeing too many connections then you are probably not using a using statement to dispose of the connection when you exit the scope of the invoking methods.

Comment: Don't forget about connection pooling.  It is OK to dispose a connection.  It will "hang around" for a while before being thrown away.  That should allow for connection reuse automatically (ADO.net does this for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a problem with Ninject closing DB contexts ...

http://bobcravens.com/2010/11/using-ninject-to-manage-critical-resources/

Answer (score 4):

Using 'using' blocks would help.  Keep in mind that ADO.net connections are 'pooled'. Pooled connections will be reused if the same connection string is used within a certain amount of time.  It should prevent piling up of all those connections like that.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point would be to make sure you don't leave context instances dangling around. Wrapping them in using blocks might do the trick.